# Select matrix based in intervals (subset function) in R

Tags: r, syntax-error, subset

I would like to subset one matrix based on `X2` collumn values. I Tryied it:

```
on <- subset(mat.num, X2 <= -3)
un <- subset(mat.num, X2 >= -1.50000 & X2 <= -0.3599999)
dn <- subset(mat.num, X2 >= -0.3599998 & X2 <= 0.5)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in subset.matrix(mat.num, X2 <= -3) : object 'X2' not found.
```

ps: I have one `X2` column:

`mat.num` head:

```
     T_EBV     X2
[1,] 0.09 -0.00777840
[2,] 0.26  0.03600431
[3,] 0.20 -0.06191900
[4,] 0.25  0.13423752
[5,] 0.42  0.06354759
[6,] -0.20  0.06303164
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix method doesn't reference column names the same way that you can with data frames. You probably want:

```
subset(mat.num, mat.num[,2] <= -3)
```

If you look at the code for `subset.matrix` you'll see that it's not evaluating the subset criteria inside any special environment:

```
if (missing(subset)) 
        subset <- TRUE
else if (!is.logical(subset)) 
        stop("'subset' must be logical")
x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop]
```

as opposed to `subset.data.frame` which is using `eval` and `substitute`.